# Does Facebook Allows To Create A Facebook Like Exhange Website Using Facebook PHP SDK.?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

i want to create a facebook like exchange website using facebook PHP sdk, does facebook allow this or not? please answer me... Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don’t participate in any “like” or “share” exchange programs.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ (13.3)

Answer (score 0):

Similer to facebook like Exchange you can go for social engine framework

```
https://www.socialengine.com/
```

Comment: just i wanna know facebook allow  to create facebook like exchange website or not. ayway tnk u for ur answer